# Sourcing a tcl script from another directory

Tags: tcl

I have two tcl scripts, one of which calls the other. The second script, 'version.tcl' is in a sub-directory ('synthesis') of the working directory.

I currently have it set up and working in the following fashion:

```
cd ./synthesis
source version.tcl
cd ../
```

I would like to condense that to one command which can source the script without having to change directories, something along the lines of:

```
source [file join [file join [[pwd] synthesis] version.tcl]]
```

Or

```
source ./synthesis/version.tcl
```

Unfortunately neither one of the above commands works. I know this should be an easy fix for someone with more familiarity with tcl than me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? `source ./syntheses/version.tcl` works fine. Perhaps in the "main" script, your `pwd` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to nest `file join` calls: this is fine: `file join [pwd] synthesis version.tcl`

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the replies! I also thought that maybe I wasn't where I thought I was in the 'main' directory, but since the cd ./synthesis approach worked, I'm fairly certain I am in the 'main' directory

Comment: @glennjackman Also, the source ./synthesis/version.tcl doesn't work when I try it. I'm running on a windows 10 if that makes any difference. I had expected it to work when I originally tried it but no luck???

Comment: Maybe version.tcl makes (incorrect) assumptions about the working directory too. But in general `source ./synthesis/version.tcl` works. If you need more help, describe in more detail how it doesn't work (error message etc).

Comment: @SchelteBron  I am using a batch file (with one line of code) which calls the 'main' tcl script which builds an HDL project in Libero 11.9. Within that 'main' tcl script I need to call version.tcl to autoupdate an SVN version register in the project. I don't see any type of error or update on the cmd prompt during the entire build. I know the build works if the cmd prompt closes after ~10 minutes, and I have a project file in my directory. If the script doesn't work, the cmd prompt aborts after ~20 seconds with no error message. This is the case if I don't use the cd ./synthesis approach.

Comment: You still haven't described what "doesn't work" means. You haven't shown what's in version.tcl. You haven't described what actually happens versus what you expect to happen. As it stands, this question can be closed with reason "Needs details or clarity". What kind of help are you wanting to see here?

Comment: I bet you are executing that batch file in a different directory than your main tcl file. If you add `puts [pwd]` in your main tcl file what does it print out?

Answer (score 3):

The `source` command reads files in other directories just fine; it uses almost exactly the same machinery as `open` to handle filenames (and that's little more than just "give it to the OS"). We know that it works; it's tested and it is something that very many people have used across many platforms.

What's going wrong is almost certainly that the code inside that file expects to have the current directory be the one that contains the script. Your options to fix that are

1. Do what you're currently doing, or a slightly more robust version of it:

   ```bash
   proc sourceInDir {directory scriptName} {
       set pwd [pwd]
       cd $directory
       try {
           uplevel 1 [list source $scriptName]
       } finally {
           cd $pwd
       }
   }
   ```
2. Update the code that you call so it accesses resources relative to the script, not to the current directory:

   ```bash
   # Put this at the top of the script, OUTSIDE procedures but INSIDE namespace eval
   variable baseDir [file dirname [file normalize [info script]]]

   # Then can access relative to that with, say:
   open [file join $baseDir foo.txt]
   ```

Comment: The second is the better code style overall, but the first is much less work when you don't control the code that you're calling.